# Beanshell PreProcessor not not finding SampleResult

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter and am struggling to implement a Beanshell PreProcessor. I have this example code taken from a post on this site -

```
File querycsv = new File("xlocalTestData.csv");

if (!querycsv.exists()){
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setRespnseMessage("Failed to find CSV file");
    SampleResult.setData("Unable to locate CSV file under path: " + querycsv.getPath(),"UTF-8");
    IsSuccess = false;
    SampleResult.setStopTestNow(true);
```

Digging around on the internet I found this import statement -

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
```

But I am getting this error when passing a corrupt file name to test for a fail if the csv file is missing -

```
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Report Service Group 1 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 5 threads for group Report Service Group 1. 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will start next loop on error 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 5 ramp-up 5 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=true 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Report Service Group 1 1-1 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: /home/brad/JMeter/ReportService/localTestData.csv Alias: /home/brad/JMeter/ReportService/localTestData.csv@1567545803 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:11 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:12 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:12 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:12 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:12 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;  File querycsv = new File("xloca . . . '' : Cannot reach instance method: setSuccessful( boolean ) from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult 
2014/03/03 13:11:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Report Service Group 1 1-2
```

Not being a Java programmer I am guessing that I don't have my include path set up? Is anyone able to point me toward a resolution?

I am running this on a Centos 6 desktop running Apache JMeter (2.11 r1554548)

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Brad

Comment: you have a typo.  .setRespnseMessage(  should be setResponseMessage(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler), not Beanshell Pre Processor.

`SampleResult` is a pre-defined variable which is available for Beanshell Sampler only, neither pre nor post processors don't have access to it.

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks DMitri, that was eductational :) I don't have a Beanshell Sampler in my version of JMeter. Or I am looking in the wrong place... I have a Beanshell Assertion. I tried adding the code to that and am now gettiing a different error - Method setData( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampleResult'. Wil try removing the call

Comment: Nice tutorial Dmitri. You write it? I have found a Beanshell Listener, is that the sampler you mention under a new name? Removing the call to setdata seemed to work, the log shows a couple of threads reporting a "Stop Test Now" and the test exits. Thaks :)

Comment: Beanshell sampler is default component for quite a long time, it's located under `Samplers`, but you have to be at Thread Group scope. If you're doing right click on a Sampler, i.e. HTTP Request or any other, you won't be able to add a child sampler, only pre/post processor, assertion, config element or listener. Just go up one level and you'll see possibility to add a sampler.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. So I was looking in the wrong place :). However, I found that the same code works with a Beanshell assertion as well. Both terminate the test and I see this in the log - "jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Test Now detected by thread: Report Service Group 1 1-1" Thanks for the help, I've been making heavy going of this.